# Windows Media Player is not in Default apps list in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-media-player

I know, this question was asked many times, but there is still no answer that can actually solve the problem. There are steps to get the WMP in Windows Optional Features, install it if missing, etc. - I did all that, and now WMP runs and plays media files. However, there is no way in Windows 10 to set it as a Default App to play media file types.

- Go to "Default apps" > "Music Player" > "Choose Default" - WMP is not there.
- "Choose default apps by file type" > ".mp3" > "Choose a default" - WMP is not there.
- "Set Defaults by app" > Windows Media Player is here! > select "Manage" > find ".mp3" > "Choose a default" - the only choice is "Look for an app in the Microsoft Store".

After a long time spent searching I found this article: https://www.ghacks.net/2016/02/16/how-to-make-any-program-the-default-on-windows-10/

Apparently after 1803 you are supposed to use hackers tools to set the Microsoft's own Windows Media Player as default. I used FileTypesMan as was suggested in the article, but when I try to change assignments for .mp3 files, I get "Error 5: Access is denied" from the tool. Also, if I right-click on an .mp3 file and select "Open with..." it still suggests me to go to Microsoft Store, open with Notepad, Paint, Word, but not Windows Media Player.

What is the proper way to make WMP the default media player, so it shows up in the Default apps list?

Comment: What edition of Windows 10 do you have installed?  What version are you running?  If you have an N edition of Windows 10, do you have the Media Pack Installed?

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound - it is version 1903, Windows 10 Enterprise. I do not think it can be N edition because it is our standard IT image for US offices. AFAIU, for N there is no WMP at all, and I would install Media Pack. But I had WMP in my install, it is just not wired to default programs. I tried to uninstall, but then I could not install it back due to some other error, so I had to recover from a backup to get WMP back...

Comment: I have WMP as an option for "Music player". Ensure it is enabled in "Turn Windows features on or off", then run [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why FileTypesMan cannot change the association type is because Windows started protecting association settings with a special secret hash. Looking in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.mp3\UserChoice`, 
I see two keys ProgId="VLC.mp3" and Hash="GmB3NDUc5ck=". I cannot change these keys because I need to know how to generate the hash. Fortunately, there is someone who figured it out: https://kolbi.cz/blog/2017/10/25/setuserfta-userchoice-hash-defeated-set-file-type-associations-per-user/

Using the hacking method and tool described in that article I was able to set the .mp3 association to WMP11.AssocFile.MP3, which is the existing association type from the properly installed WMP:
`SetUserFTA.exe .mp3 WMP11.AssocFile.MP3`

After running this command, the .mp3 registry entry changed to ProgId="WMP11.AssocFile.MP3" and Hash="+ArSXyKb5G8=".

This solved my immediate usability problem, it would still be great to know if there is a proper method that can be recommended to the users.

Answer (score 1):

I also saw the "access denied" error in FileTypesMan on my system, so I analyzed it with Sysinternal's Process Monitor to see where it was failing on. Apparently the default permissions of the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MP3\shell\play` registry key are so that only the built-in TrustedInstaller account is allowed to make changes (and not, for example, administrator accounts).

This can be fixed by adding write permissions for administrator accounts to that registry key. The easiest way I've found to do that is by using the RegDACL tool. The tool isn't available anymore on the author's official website but you can still download it [here](https://www.heise.de/download/product/regdacl-61765/download/danke?id=61765-1).

After putting `RegDACL.exe` in a directory on your PATH environment variable, open an administrator Command Prompt and run these commands:

```
regdacl "HKCR\WMP11.AssocFile.MP3\shell\play" /GGA:F
regdacl "HKCR\WMP11.AssocFile.MP3\shell\play\command" /GGA:F
```

( `/GGA:F`: **g**rant to the predefined **g**roup "**A**dministrators" **f**ull access )

After the commands have been executed successfully, you should be able to use FileTypesMan to change the assignments.